# when should we dereference explicit in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm doing exercises in rustlings. In vecs2.rs, the code is:

```rust
fn vec_loop(mut v: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    for element in v.iter_mut() {
        // TODO: Fill this up so that each element in the Vec `v` is
        // multiplied by 2.

        element =  element * 2; // error here!!!


    }

    // At this point, `v` should be equal to [4, 8, 12, 16, 20].
    v
}

fn vec_map(v: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.iter().map(|element| {
        // TODO: Do the same thing as above - but instead of mutating the
        // Vec, you can just return the new number!
        element * 2 // no error
    }).collect()
}
```

but I got an error:

```
error[E0369]: cannot multiply `&mut i32` by `{integer}`
  --> exercises/vecs/vecs2.rs:16:28
   |
16 |         element =  element * 2; // error here!!!
   |                    ------- ^ - {integer}
   |                    |
   |                    &mut i32
   |
help: `*` can be used on `i32` if you dereference the left-hand side
   |
16 |         element =  *element * 2; // error here!!!
   |                    +
```

I'm confused about why we should dereference explicit in `vec_loop`, but no need to dereference in `vec_map` (if so, it should be `*element * 2`). I'd confess that I always use reference like it is the value and never use like a pointer in other language( `*some_ref` ).

Comment: _"but no need to dereference in `vec_map`"_ [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Add.html#tymethod.add) [`Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) and other arithmetic traits are also implemented for reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd confess that I always use reference like it is the value and never use like a pointer in other language(`*some_ref`).

A reference is always a pointer so *technically* this is wrong, however practically it often works for two reasons:

1. `.` automatically derefs, so there's no need to deref' when accessing an attribute or calling a method (it would be rather inconvenient due to the precedence too)
2. what you're getting confused by here is that *it's common for traits to be partially or fully implemented on references for convenience*

In this case, if you go check the [implementations of `Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html#implementors) you will see:

```rust
impl Mul<&i32> for &i32
impl Mul<&i32> for i32
impl Mul<i32> for i32
impl Mul<i32> for &i32
```

So for convenience the standard library provides an implementation of `*` for every combination of `i32` and `&i32`.

Note, however, that there is no such implementation for `&mut i32`, which is an entirely separate type. And the type of `element` in the loop, as [that's what `iter_mut()` hands out](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html#impl-Iterator-for-IterMut%3C%27a,+T%3E):

```rust
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T
    ...
}
```

Which is why you can't just multiply an `&mut i32` with an `i32`.

Note that it still won't work if you dereference `element`, because now you're trying to assign an `i32` (the result of your multiplication) to a variable of type `&mut i32` (which furthermore is not itself `mut`). So you'll have to write:

```rust
*element = *element * 2;
```

at which point you can just write the more obvious

```rust
*element *= 2;
```

which goes through [`MulAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.MulAssign.html), which expects a mutable LHS, and thus can use either of the existing implementations:

```rust
impl MulAssign<&i32> for i32
impl MulAssign<i32> for i32
```

Note that there's still no `MulAssign<&mut i32>`, so `*expression *= expression` still fail to compile, which I find funny (though it's a rare issue to encounter).

Comment: thx! it is amazing that &i32 and &mut i32 are different types, which I never know before.

Comment: While the syntax doesn't necessarily look it, you should think of `&T` and `&mut T` as `Ref<T>` and `RefMut<T>`, they're really smart pointers (although all of their smarts are compile-time constraints), but built very deep into the language and with a lot of special handling (tbf `Box` also has a few things which only it can do).